# Regexp Substring From URL

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, substring

I need to retrieve some word from url :

```
WebViewActivity - https://google.com/search/?term=iphone_5s&amp;utm_source=google&amp;utm_campaign=search_bar&amp;utm_content=search_submit
```

return I want :

```
search/iphone_5s
```

but I'm stuck and not really understand how to use regexp_substr to get that data.

I'm trying to use this query

```
regexp_substr(web_url, '\google.com/([^}]+)\/', 1,1,null,1)
```

which only return the 'search' word, and when I try

```
regexp_substr(web_url, '\google.com/([^}]+)\&', 1,1,null,1)
```

it turns out I get all the word until the last '&'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `REGEXP_REPLACE` to match the whole string but capture two substrings and replace with two backreferences to the capture group values:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
    'WebViewActivity - https://google.com/search/?term=iphone_5s&amp;utm_source=google&amp;utm_campaign=search_bar&amp;utm_content=search_submit',
    '.*//google\.com/([^/]+/).*[?&]term=([^&]+).*',
    '\1\2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36jlhn/2) and the [online Oracle demo](https://rextester.com/XRGT90463).

**Pattern details**

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `//google\.com/` - a `//google.com/` substring
- `([^/]+/)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `/` and then a `/`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `[?&]term=` - `?` or `&` and a `term=` substring
- `([^&]+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more chars other than `&`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

**NOTE**: To use this approach and get an empty result if the match is not found, append `|.+` at the end of the regex pattern.

Comment: Is there a risk to catch an URL such as `https://example.com/?redirect_to=https://google.com/search/?term=iphone_5s` ? I'm note 100% sure due to how the URL would be encoded.

Comment: thank you, it works. but what if the web url becomes google.co.uk ?

Comment: @BenoîtZu Sure this string will get matched, but that can be easily fixed if there is a clear set of requirements for the input string. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/36jlhn/3) is a variation of the current approach.

Comment: @DedeSoetopo Replace `com` with `[^/]+`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/36jlhn/4).